# What will happen if I remove "essential components" for Gnome?

Tags: gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome 3. There are some applications that I don't use or need, for example Totem. When I click remove in the Software Center (or in Synaptic), it says "gnome-core" and/or "The gnome desktop environment - essential components" will be removed as well.

I removed these applications about a month ago by ignoring the prompts and once I restarted, Ubuntu would not load and would simply sit there at the loading screen. I'm not sure if removing gnome-core caused this issue, but I really want to remove some of these applications.

What is gnome-core and how do I know what essential components are going to be removed? Should I go forth with removing them anyways?

Comment: It is not clear whether you've already saw problem after you removed those gnome-core components, or you are asking what could be happened if you do so.

Comment: [..]I removed these applications about a month ago by ignoring the prompts and once I restarted, Ubuntu would not load and would simply sit there at the loading screen.[..]. There you go there's your answer.

Comment: there are some packages commonly used by both vital and normal applications. Make sure you removal of a package does not cause a chain of other packages to be removed. Always be aware of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

i was just testing this to check this out, by un-intalling totem! there should be no problem todo so!

suggestion do a re-install of gnome-common and gnome-session using synaptic by preference (as i don't like the software center)

and reboot the sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.
then open synaptic and remove totem.
if you want to remove the games i just remove them one by one or tomboy etc. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Gnome-core is a package. From your description of the events (I can't confirm with [this package checker](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-core) because it doesn't have your Ubuntu version), I suspect that `gnome-core` is a dependency of `totem`.

To confirm this, enter the following into a terminal:

> apt-cache depends totem

This will get all the dependencies of the the totem package. If 'gnome-core' appears in that list, you will know that totem requires `gnome-core` to be installed.

To get the details of `gnome-core`, type into a terminal:

> apt-cache show gnome-core

Scroll down to see the description (mine on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
Description-en_AU: GNOME Desktop Environment -- essential components
These are the core components of the GNOME Desktop environment, an
intuitive and attractive desktop.
.
This meta-package depends on a basic set of programs, including a file
manager, an image viewer, a web browser, a video player and other tools.
.
It contains the official “core” modules of the GNOME desktop.
```

To know what programs will be removed if you remove `gnome-core`, you will need to check what its "reverse dependencies" are:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends gnome-core
gnome-core
Reverse Depends:
  gnome-audio
  gnome
  bluetile
```