# Uninstall apps installed with GNOME3

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I have installed GNOME 3 desktop environment in Ubuntu 12.04 and want to free some space by removing apps I don't need. When I try to do so via Software Center, I get a warning that the Gnome Desktop Environment must be removed as well.

[image]

As I have seen here: 
[What will happen if I remove "essential components" for Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97442/what-will-happen-if-i-remove-essential-components-for-gnome)  proceeding would indeed mess things up. 
So is there no safe way to remove those apps installed with gnome3?

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem if you remove a package such as "ubuntu-desktop". It's just a dummy package. I've removed it many times to get rid of apps I don't use. I really hate the way Ubuntu links packages like that. It makes it seem scary. That said, is it really taking up that much space for one app?

Comment: Well, it's not just one app, and I have and ocd-like thing with apps I don't use. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I know the feeling. You're welcome :)